# Rollup Exceptions to preserveModules

Tags: javascript, rollup

I use a rollup plugin called `rollup-plugin-lit-css` to transform `.css` files into javascript modules. That plugin isdead-simple, it essentially just appends `export default` to the file.

My rollup config uses `preserveModules` and `output.dir` to avoid bundling modules.

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import litcss from 'rollup-plugin-lit-css';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  preserveModules: true,
  input: 'src/a.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'es',
  },
  plugins: [
    litcss(),
    babel({ babelrc: true }),
    resolve({ browser: true }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
};
```

### Current Behavior

Let's say that `a` imports `a.css` and also `b`. The current situation turns this:

```
src/
├── a.js
├── a.css
├── b.js
```

into this:

```
dist/
├── a.js
├── a.css
├── b.js
```

### Desired Output

I would like, instead, to get this:

```
dist/
├── a.js
├── b.js
```

With the transformed contents of `a.css` bundled into `a.js`

Answer (score 2):

`preserveModules` can't be used to selectively create separate chunks, please use [`manualChunks`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#manualchunks) instead.

```
{
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'es',
    chunkFileNames: '[name].js'
  },
  manualChunks: id => path.parse(id).name
}
```

In this case, `a.js` and `a.css` have the same chunk name `a`, and `a.js` will be created for them. `chunkFileNames` specifies output file names and is required.

Complete config:

```
import path from 'path'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import litcss from 'rollup-plugin-lit-css'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'

export default {
  input: 'a.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'es',
    chunkFileNames: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    litcss(),
    babel({ babelrc: true }),
    resolve({ browser: true }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
  manualChunks: id => path.parse(id).name
}
```